# Auto rounding of double values

Tags: c#, .net, automation, numbers, rounding

Someone has any idea how can I auto round double values to 2 decimal digits? I have an application which performs some simple calculations in many places and sometime I'm getting numbers with a lot of decimal numbers such as 21.248123. Is there any way to specify .NET to use only 2 decimal number in every place (through CultureInfo maybe?).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this at least when displaying the message to the user by using `myDouble.ToString("0.00")`.

If you want to round the value itself use `Math.Round(myDouble,2)`.

Note that even when rounding the `double`, you might get many decimals due to floating point aritmetics, so I would use the former `ToString` variant regardless when displaying the value to the user to make sure that it gets displayed with only two decimals.

Comment: I'm aware of ToString overloads. That's not what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway

Comment: See the Math.Round also. You can't actually force the double to actually contain two digits after the decimal. If you need that kind of handling, I think using the decimal class can help you out.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Thanks :)